# How to convert a big list of comma-separated numbers into float

Tags: python, csv

I need to make a script, which takes 2 columns of data from 2 columns of .csv file and then plot a graph based on this data. I managed to export data from columns as such list (there are actually 140 nubmers, but you got the idea):

```
['0', '0,1', '0,2', '0,3', '0,4', '0,5', '0,6', '0,7', '0,8000001', '0,9000001', '1', '1,1', '1,2']
```

The problem is, when i try to plot with this data, matplotlib gives an error, because it's not float numbers. And I can't convert this data to float, because numbers are separated with commas, instead of dots. So, how can I replace all this commas with dots or maybe there are some other easier solutions to this? I'm totally new to Python.

**Update**: My mistake, the format I exported data in is not list, but DICT. I could succesfully convert it into a long string, but can't find a way to convert it into an array of floats. Thanks for all your help.

Comment: Basic usage of a string replace operation, or?

Answer (score 5):

```
n = ['0', '0,1', '0,2', '0,3', '0,4', '0,5', '0,6', '0,7',
     '0,8000001', '0,9000001', '1', '1,1', '1,2']
[float(m.replace(",", ".")) for m in n]
# => [0.0, 0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5, 0.6, 0.7,
#     0.8000001, 0.9000001, 1.0, 1.1, 1.2]
```